# How to enable or disable collapsing in CollapsibleToolbarLayout in android?

Tags: android-layout, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

```
**Main Layout**:

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/White">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@color/white"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:text="Journal Name, Volume No, Issue"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/article_listing_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

**Layout**:article_listing_content

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rv_container"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:elevation="50dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/error_msg_container"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/error_msg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to disable the collapsing of the title field (collapsing_title - TextView inside CollapsingToolbarLayout) if there is not enough data in the recycler view. ie Collapsing should only happen if there is more data / scrolling is required, else collapsing should be disabled.

Answer (score 3):

You can "disable" this collapsing behavior by modifying your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`'s `app:layout_scrollFlags` attribute.

As a `layout_` attribute, this is part of the parent's `LayoutParams` (i.e. `AppBarLayout.LayoutParams`). As expected, this class exposes the method `setScrollFlags()`.

To disable collapsing:

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsing = 
    (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);

AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) collapsing.getLayoutParams();

params.setScrollFlags(0);

collapsing.setLayoutParams(params);
```

To re-enable collapsing, simply replace the `setScrollFlags()` call with one that passes in your original flags:

```
params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED);
```

Comment: Yes, but how do you know if content fits screen or no?